# Log work in JIRA

Tags: jira, time-tracking

I'm creating a list of tools that help to log work in JIRA (apart from the worklog features provided in the JIRA interface itself).

Tools and utilities I found on the plugins.atlassian.com and googling around, are

- [Agile Plugin](http://www.atlassian.com/software/greenhopper/)
- [Worklog Assistant](https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/6284)
- [Hitsoft Timetracker](https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/6998)
- [Universal Time Tracker](https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/9096)
- [Worklog sheet](https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/6502)
- [Atlassian Connectors](http://www.atlassian.com/software/ideconnector/)
- [Tempo Plugin](http://www.tempoplugin.com)
- [JIRA Client](http://almworks.com/jiraclient/)
- [Talia](http://dialoogsolutions.com/)

Does anyone know about other tools that I'm overlooking ?
Any opinion on these tools ?

Francis

Comment: Your list looks good enough! I doubt you will get time enough to use all of them and still be productive.

Comment: I developed a little tool that might be helpful: http://super-productivity.com/

Comment: i use this open source one https://github.com/web-pal/chronos-timetracker

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I keep a list of various time tracking plugins here:

http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRACOM/Using+JIRA+For+Time+Tracking

Thanks,
Christina Bang
Atlassian Sales Engineer

Comment: Link is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this page while I was looking for some easy to use client tool for my ubuntu.
The orginal worklog assistant does not work well with my xmonad. (some windowing issues with java)

In the past I've written a jira-console tool in ruby but it's broken now :(

Some dependencies of soap4r not working well.

Anyway you can find it here : [jira-console](https://github.com/ypetya/jira-console)

Have a nice day!

Comment: This is the oldest reply to anything ever but what is the issue you have with xmonad? Worklog Assistant is written in C++, not Java and uses Qt so if you have any solution for Qt applications for xmonad, it should also apply for Worklog Assistant.

Comment: Hi. I haven't checked it for a while, but added some xmonad config to set up the window manager name (*startupHook = setWMName "LG3D"*). It solves some problems with window resizeing.